# Angular. Watch for selected values inside ng-repeat list and pass them to service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to AngularJS and tried to find solution with no success.
I have dynamic form with nested ng-repeats as custom directives. Here is my structure in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DeF8iYNwcHzoh2a2tsPD?p=preview).
In directive "rule" i have two selects, one for parameters another one for values.

```
<rule ng-repeat="rule in cc.route.rules track by rule.id">


   <li class="second-level">
        {{ $index +1 }}
        <select ng-change="ic.getParamName(mc.main.routes[$parent.$index].rules[rule.id].param)"
                ng-model="mc.main.routes[$parent.$index].rules[rule.id].param"
                ng-options="param.name as param.name for param in ic.params"></select>
        <select ng-change="" ng-model="mc.main.routes[$parent.$index].rules[rule.id].value"
                ng-options="value.code as value.name for value in ic.values"></select>
        <button ng-click="ic.removeRule(rule,$parent.$index)">del</button>
    </li>
</rule>
```

When i select the parameter it fires the function with passing the parameter's name. 
In the controller of current directive i catch this parameter by switch case and pass it to the certain method in service. Then i get the list of values for this parameter.

```
case "Countries":
    vm.values = DataService.getCountries();
    break;

case "Cities":
    DataService.getCities().then(function(data){
        vm.values = data;
    });
    break;
```

My issue is that I want to get cities only if some country is already selected in previous ng-repeats(rules) of current route (we can catch only the last selected country if there are more than one), and when i'm adding the new rule with cities, pass the code of the country selected above as argument to the certain method in service to make http request and get cities for this country. Same issue with OS and OS versions.
How i can watch for rules in current route and path the codes of countries and OS to the service with adding new rule?

**UPDATE:**
Let's say we add new route and want there 2 rules with country "USA" and city "Dallas". We need to add new rule to this route, choose the parameter "Countries" in the first select and the value "USA" in the second. Then we want to choose "Dallas", but my server can return american cities only if i pass the country code "US" to http request. So at the moment when we add new rule and choose the parameter "Cities" we need to get all values from all selects above, check if there was country and get it country code, then path it to the service with getCities() method.

Thanks! And please let me know if it is not well understood.

Comment: Read this several times and can't really make sense of what the specific problem is or what exactly you want to watch

Comment: Please see my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/DeF8iYNwcHzoh2a2tsPD?p=preview, there i have DataService with http request to get cities, i need to pass there a country code. I need this at the moment when i add new rule and choose the parameter "Cities" and if some country was already selected above in the current route.

Comment: Already looked at that and it still is not clear

Comment: updated my post with a little use case

Comment: So basically you are trying to figure out how to pass `code` into service `getCities: function (code)` ?

Comment: I know how to pass code into service (DataService.getCities('US'), first i need to find and get this code into controller

Comment: So can't you just add a method in `ng-change` and pass in the index so you can reference it?

Comment: Yes, i can pass value of the second select by ng-change but it will not be accessible for new rule because of new scope. Maybe i need watch method in parent scope?

Comment: Thanks! Your tips helped me to make it work! I've just passed the value to scope variable in the Route controller, and it will be rewritten at each change of second select. Now i get cities correctly. It still has some scope problems but i'll fix them.

Answer (score 0):

### Re-factor the User Interface

[image]

Currently as designed the UI has an <kbd>Add new Rule</kbd> button that allows the user to add illegal rules. As shown in the screenshot, the user has erroneously added two countries. And as stated by the OP, users can add a <kbd>Cities</kbd> rule before a country is selected.

The advice is to change the <kbd>Add new Rule</kbd> button to a drop-down menu that has illegal options disabled. When rules are added or removed, the controller should enable or disable appropriate legal items.

The `ng-options` directive allows a controller to enable and disable options using the **`disable when`** clause. For more information, visit [AngularJS ng-options API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

The UI should not allow the user to add illegal rules. Also the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button should be disabled until the form is complete. Users should be given advice on how to complete the form. "Add Route", "Select Rule", "Select Country", etc.

---

### XHR Request Issues

In the [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/DeF8iYNwcHzoh2a2tsPD?p=preview) the `DataService.getCities` function has several problems.

```
//WRONG
function DataService() {
    return {
        getCities: function (code) {    
            $http.get('/get_cities?country_code=' + code)
                .success(function (response) {
                    return(response.data);
                });
```

The `return` statement doesn't return a value to the `getCities` function. It returns values to the anonymous function inside the `.success` method and the `.success` method **ignores** return values.

```
//BETTER
function DataService($http, $q) {
    return {
        getCities: function (code) {
            if (isBad(code)) {
                return $q.reject("BAD Country Code");
            };
            //Otherwise send request
            var getCitiesPromise = (  
                $http.get('/get_cities?country_code=' + code)
                    .then(function onFulfilled (response) {
                         return(response.data);
                    });
            );
            return getCitiesPromise;
        }
    }
};
```

In this example, the `getCities` function checks the country code and returns a rejected promise if the code is bad. If the country code is OK, an XHR request is sent and a promise is return fulfilled with the data or rejected with the `$http` service error.

---

Comment: Thanks for your concern, I'll save your solution, but for passing the country code to the service i need to know it :). This is my issue. Please see my update at the end of the post.